# xpath tag not sure what to put

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have a page that I am trying to get the price off of.  Here's a peek at the line.

```
<div itemprop="price" class="js-price-display Price Price--flair Price--medium hide-content-m price-display"> <span class="Price-sup">$</span>34<span class="Price-mark">.</span>96 </div>']
```

I've tried a bunch of different ways to get it but keep coming up short.  The best I got was these 2.  (The price is $34.96 by the way)

```
selector.xpath('//div[@itemprop="price"]/text()').extract()
```

which gives me

```
[u' ', u'34', u' ', u' ', u'34', u'96 ']
```

and this way

```
selector.xpath('//div[@class="js-price-display Price Price--flair Price--medium hide-content-m price-display"]').extract()
```

which is giving me this result

```
[u'<div itemprop="price" class="js-price-display Price Price--flair Price--medium hide-content-m price-display"> <span class="Price-sup">$</span>34<span class="Price-mark">.</span>96 </div>']
```

If I get just the span it gives me the $ and the . but i don't know what that attribute(or property or value or whatever) its called "after" the span there at the end where the actual amount is.  I would love to get the first part, the period, and the second part but I will take anything better than what I got.  Lastly, I ran this bit of test code to see the properties of the chunk of the webpage I put in there.  Here's what I ran

```
for item in selector.xpath('.//*[@itemprop]'):
     print "Item:", item.xpath('@itemtype').extract()
     for property in item.xpath('.//*[@itemprop]'):
         print "Property:",
         print property.xpath('@itemprop').extract(),
         print property.xpath('string(.)').extract()
         for position, attribute in enumerate(property.xpath('@*'), start=1):
             print "attribute: name=%s; value=%s" % (
                 property.xpath('name(@*[%d])' % position).extract(),
                 attribute.extract())
         print
     print
```

and I got these results.

```
C:\Python27\bff\bff\spiders>python test.py
Item: [u'http://schema.org/Offer']
Property: [u'priceCurrency'] [u'']
attribute: name=[u'itemprop']; value=priceCurrency
attribute: name=[u'content']; value=USD

Property: [u'price'] [u' $34.96 ']
attribute: name=[u'itemprop']; value=price
attribute: name=[u'class']; value=js-price-display Price Price--stylized  Price--large hide-content display-inline-m price-display

Property: [u'price'] [u' $34.96 ']
attribute: name=[u'itemprop']; value=price
attribute: name=[u'class']; value=js-price-display Price Price--flair Price--medium hide-content-m price-display

Property: [u'availability'] [u'']
attribute: name=[u'itemprop']; value=availability
attribute: name=[u'itemtype']; value=http://schema.org/ItemAvailability
attribute: name=[u'content']; value=InStock
```

How is it like BOOM, exactly like I need mine to show and I can't get it?  I tried using both those classes and both those itemprop values and keep getting stuff similar to what I posted.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `/text()` you'll get only text nodes that is direct child of current context element. And by using `//text()` you'll get all text nodes within current context element, either direct child or nested, but separated texts will be returned as individual text nodes.

What you need is to locate the `div` elements and then call XPath `string()` function on each `div`, that's what your test code do to output the expected value. If there is only one `div` at a time, then the following XPath will also work :

```
selector.xpath('string(//div[@itemprop="price"])').extract()
```

Otherwise you need to loop through the `div` elements and then call `string()` in the `for` loop body.

Comment: Nailed it!  I was getting everything in the tag but didn't know changing it to a string would trim it down to just the text too!  Thanks for helping me keep my sanity.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
//div[@itemprop='price']//text()
```

for your xpath expression.  Note the two slashes before `text()`.  Those will cause it to go to any depth and pull out all text nodes, including the ones in the span.

I haven't used scrapy, but if your function just returns a list, you should be able to use

```
''.join(resultlist)
```

to put that together into one expression then.

If you want to try to get JUST the price, without the dollar sign, you can also use

```
//div[@itemprop='price']/descendant-or-self::*[not(@class='Price-sup')]/text()
```

This will work as long as nothing is more than one level beyond the div (do NOT try that double slash trick here, or it will be identical to the simpler example, and defeat the purpose of removing that dollar sign).  What this grabs is all text nodes either directly under that div, or in the spans inside of it (except for the dollar sign).  You again will have to join your results.

Also note that you have a space inside that div before anything else.  Either method is going to grab that space, so you may need to trim your result.

Comment: Thank you Matthew, This code, along with the join, got me closer but doubled the price like so. `$34.96  $34.96`  The second optin you gave was even closer but still had a bit of doubling up after the join `34.  34.96`  Thank you very much for the try though.

Comment: I don't know why it would have doubled it.  I tested each of those expressions on your original example using lxml in python and they worked perfectly.  I'm not familiar with scrapy, so it is possible it does something strange with the expressions causing that.  In lxml the first gives `[' ','$','34,'.','96 ']` and the second gives the same without the dollar sign.  That is strange that scrapy gives a different result.

Comment: Not sure about scrapy but when I ran your code I was just doing it through python and got the double.  I just noticed that there is a section right below it with a different class name but the same itemprop name and everything else the same.  I think that's where I was getting the doubling otherwise I bet yours would have worked.  Thanks.

Comment: I only had that one div to test with.  If there is more than one element that could be matched with that itemprop attribute, that is likely why it doubled.  Adding a position selector may be able to fix that `//div[@itemprop='price'][1]`